# How to filter one category with multiple strings from a dynamic checkbox into a pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, filter, pipe

I'm asking this question again because I did not get a clear answer before.

If this is done better without pipes, please, show me how, or point me to a source where I can learn to do so.

I have multiple filters in a pipe in order to filter out smartphones by characteristics. Currently, it works only for one checkbox per category, but I'd like to be able to include multiple filters per category (Ex. Search for both samsung and Apple brands) This checkbox is dynamically generated, based on an API call, so I'd like for the pipe to accept an indeterminate number of arguments. Thanks in advance!

I have attempted to do a for loop within the pipe, and apply an array of strings as an argument.

filter-component.html

```
<mat-drawer-container style="overflow-y: hidden;" class="example-container">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened>
    <div class="wrapper" #wrapper>
      <div class="sidebar" [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': marginSize, 'position': sideNavPosition, 'z-index':20, 'height':open===true? collapsedHeight : '100%'}">
        <ul class="list-sidebar bg-defoult">
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".filtermenu" class="collapsed active">
              <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
              <span class="nav-label">Filter</span>
              <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#brandlabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#brand" class="collapsed active" id="brandlabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Brand</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="brand" *ngFor="let Product of brand; let i = index">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="f{{i}}" value="f{{i}}" (change)="setSearchBrand(Product)" /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>

            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#batterylabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#battery" class="collapsed active" id="batterylabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Battery</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="battery" *ngFor="let Product of battery">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{Product}}"  (change)="setSearchBattery(Product)" /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>
```

Product-ListComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Product } from '../../partner/Product';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  open: boolean;
  marginSize: string;
  sideNavPosition: string;
  collapsedHeight: string;

  brand: Product["brand"];
  battery: Product["battery"];
  camera: Product["camera"];
  color: Product["color"];
  //phoneCondition: Product["phoneCondition"];
  ram: Product["ram"];
  resolution: Product["resolution"];
  storage: Product["storage"];

  searchBrand: string = "";
  searchBattery: string = "";
  searchCamera: string = "";
  searchCondition: string = "";
  searchColor: string = "";
  searchRam: string = "";
  searchResolution: string = "";
  searchStorage: string = "";



  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private router: Router) { }
  products: any[];
  prod: Object[];
  ngOnInit() {

    this.marginSize = '0px';
    this.sideNavPosition = "relative";
    this.open = false;``
    this.getProduct();


    this.productService.brandFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.brand = data;
    });
    this.productService.batteryFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.battery = data;
    });
    this.productService.cameraFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.camera = data;
    });
    this.productService.colorFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.color = data;
    });
    this.productService.resolutionFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.resolution = data;
    });
    // this.productService.conditionFilter().subscribe(data => {
    //   this.phoneCondition = data;
    // });
    this.productService.ramFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.ram = data;
    });
    this.productService.storageFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.storage = data;
    });

  }
  clearFilters() {
    this.setSearchBrand('');
    this.searchBattery = '';
    this.setSearchCamera('');
    this.setSearchCondition('');
    this.setSearchColor('');
    this.searchRam = '';
    this.setSearchResolution('');
    this.searchStorage = '';
  }
  getProduct() {
    this.productService.getProduct().subscribe(
      product => {
        this.products = product.body;
        console.log(product);
      });

  }
  setSearchBrand(name: string) {

    this.searchBrand = name;
    return this.searchBrand;

  }
  setSearchBattery(name: string) {

    this.searchBattery;
    return this.searchBattery;

  }
  setSearchCamera(name: string) {

    this.searchCamera = name;
    return this.searchCamera;

  }
  setSearchCondition(name: string) {

    this.searchCondition = name;
    return this.searchCondition;

  }
  setSearchColor(name: string) {

    this.searchColor = name;
    return this.searchColor;

  }
  setSearchRam(name: string) {

    this.searchRam = name;
    return this.searchRam;

  }
  setSearchResolution(name: string) {

    this.searchResolution = name;
    return this.searchResolution;

  }
  setSearchStorage(name: string) {

    this.searchStorage = name;
    return this.searchStorage;

  }
  viewProducts() {
    this.router.navigate(["/customers/home"])
  }

  detailss(product: any) {
    this.productService.setProductDetails(product);
    console.log(product)
    this.router.navigate(["/customers/details"]);
  }
  details(products) {
    this.router.navigate(["/customers/home"]);
  }
```

brand-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'brandFilter'
})
export class BrandFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchBrand: string[], searchBattery: string, searchCamera: string, searchColor: string
  ,searchRam: string,searchResolution: string,searchStorage: string ): any[] {
    if (items && items.length){
      return items.filter(item =>{
          if (searchBrand && item.brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBrand) === -1){
              return false;
          }
          if (searchBattery && item.battery.toString().indexOf(searchBattery) === -1){
              return false;
          }
          if (searchCamera && item.camera.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchCamera.toLowerCase()) === -1){
              return false;
          }
          if (searchColor && item.color.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchColor.toLowerCase()) === -1){
            return false;
          }
          // if (searchCondition && item.phoneCondition.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchCondition.toLowerCase()) === -1){
          //   return false;
          // }
          if (searchRam && item.ram.toString().indexOf(searchRam) === -1){
            return false;
          }
          if (searchResolution && item.resolution.indexOf(searchResolution) === -1){
            return false;
          }
          if (searchStorage && item.storage.toString().indexOf(searchStorage) === -1){
            return false;
          }

          return true;
     })
  }
    else{
        return items;
    }

  }
}
```

As I said. The code currently allows for filtering of one option out of each category. I would like to refactor, or redo this to make it so that each category can have multiple filters (ex. search for brand, and filter phones from both apple and samsung)

Comment: can you add a stackblitz for your services add sample response using of(...yourdata...) in your service class so you don't have to change a lot of code

Comment: I don't know how to do that with this project. This is a small part of a much larger project.

Comment: Are you sure  your filter pipe is working? Filter condition should be `if (searchBrand && searchBrand.indexOf(item.brand.toLowerCase()) === -1)` if you are searching `searchBrand` array. This also handles multiple filters as you wanted.

Comment: It does work. It's only working for one item though

Comment: @KevinWilde - `item.brand` is a string, when you call `indexOf()` on a string you are calling [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). You have to call [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on `searchBrand` array.

Comment: So, if I make the change to an array, how do i check all strings in the array are checked? I've tried forEach and a for loop

Comment: thx for the help btw

Comment: Oh, I just understood what you were saying. I'll check

Comment: So, it didn't actually work like I was expecting. It only returns the first result when it matches. Otherwise it makes everything disappear

Comment: @KevinWilde - You have to tag me with my username, if not I won't get notifications when you reply here under your question. "It makes everything disappear" means none of the items matched the filter criteria. Can you post the JSON data in your question and explain clearly what you want with a sample input and expected output?